# Angular: MatSort not sorting the table based on column header

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to Angular, I am working on a project where I need to sort the table based on the column, so I am using MatSort from angular material, https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples Table with Sorting.
However I can able to get the table along with the values but I couldn't get the table to sort.

Here's my code.

admin-user.component.html:

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!-- UserID Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="userid">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.userId}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="username">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.userName}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Title Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="booktitle">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Title </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bookTitle}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Author Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="bookname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Author </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.bookAuthor}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Issue Date Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="issuedate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Issue Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.issueDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

admin-user.component.ts:

```
export class AdminUserComponent implements OnInit {
users: User2[];
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'userid',
    'username',
    'booktitle',
    'bookname',
    'issuedate'
];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IssueDetail>;

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

issueList: IssueDetail[];

constructor(
    public userService: UserService,
    public bookService: BookService,
    public router: ActivatedRoute
) {
    // this.issueList = this.router.snapshot.data['resolvedData'];
    // console.log(this.issueList);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.issueList = [];
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users.filter(user => user.checkout.length > 0);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.users[i].checkout.length; j++) {
                console.log(this.users[i].checkout);
                this.issueList.push(
                    new IssueDetail(
                        this.users[i].id,
                        this.users[i].name,
                        this.users[i].checkout[j].book.title,
                        this.users[i].checkout[j].book.author,
                        this.users[i].checkout[j].startDate + ''
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        console.log(this.issueList);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.issueList);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
}}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlejJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxdFI.png)

IssueDetail is a class like this:

```
export class IssueDetail {
constructor(
    public userId: number,
    public userName: string,
    public bookTitle: string,
    public bookAuthor: string,
    public issueDate: string
) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.bookTitle = bookTitle;
    this.bookAuthor = bookAuthor;
    this.issueDate = issueDate;
}}
```

I also observed that in every example, they are making use of interface. But for my code I am trying to sort on 'Class'. But I don't know whether this makes any difference or not.

Comment: Reproduce this issue in the stackblitz. So, that we can check the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this lifecycle hook:** (**ngAfterViewInit**)

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
```

eg. of mat-table:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.date | date }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I tried to implementing that, but I get error in the console "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined
    at AdminUserComponent.push../src/app/admin-user/admin-user.component.ts.AdminUserComponent.ngAfterViewInit"

Comment: tbh there is nothing wrong in your code, but check the import : import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

Comment: Remove table, td and th tags from the html they are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
...
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.issueList);
...
```

to this:

```
this.dataSource.data = this.issueList;
```

This way you are not creating new object and just change the data. I have similar issue and got it fixed by this approach. Another issue could be using the *ngIf in some parent container.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is ok, What I have seen, Try to the following code

```
setTimeout(() => { 
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}, 0);
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxneqnvvjvo?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: I tried the above code after this line, "this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.issueList);" But it didn't change anything

Comment: Consider using ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Should not be using `setTimeout` here its not necessary.